# What to use: Table store vs. prepareTable

Tags: model, jtable

What is the reason a Joomla integrated component like `contacts` sets `modified` and `modified_by` while saving once in the `prepareTable()` method of the Model and also in the `storeTable()` method?

Is this not redundant? Should this not be done in one place? What's the best way to update data like that?